# Looking for MapGuide 2.1.0 web extensions / web studio - where am I going wrong?

Tags: installation, mapguide

I am trying to get to grips with MapGuide Open Source 2.1.0, and the first stumbling block is the Windows installer (!).

I got the main binary from [the MapGuide download page](http://mapguide.osgeo.org/download/releases/2.1.0) which has the description 'executable that will install the MapGuide Server and MapGuide Web Extensions'. From what I can gather, previous versions of MapGuide (e.g. 2.0.2) had two separate installers - one for the server and another for the web extensions, but the 2.1.0 installer is supposed to bundle the two.

This being the case, why can't I see a web studio directory inside C:\Program Files\OSGeo\MapGuide\Web\www ? It seems like web studio is not installed.

I tried installing the 2.0.2 web studio from its separate installer but that seems to be causing problems.

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I think the web studio is no longer supported and no longer being developed. Try Maestro instead!

Comment: Yes unfortunately this is the case, I eventually saw the news in one of the archived mailing list exchanges. I kind of wish the documentation or just the web site was more up to date / told you more useful information, but then I generally wish this about every OS product I work with. I am such a n00b user I'm not allowed to upvote yet.

Comment: Web Studio is no longer bundled, because it has been pulled out of the MapGuide OS svn repo as there was nobody to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

Logical question: which of the three configuration options did you choose while installing: bundled configuration, IIS configuration or manual configuration?

In the latter case it is normal that nothing is installed.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken web studio comes with the autodesk subscription. (they could have changed that since I last downloaded).